# NelmioApiDocBundle 4 how upload file in attributes

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, nelmioapidocbundle

I have a problem with uploading files using nelmio version 4 with arguments, the documentation is quite poor and I can't find a solution.

You can't use in: 'formData' which worked in earlier versions, I also tried zwagger examples and it didn't work either. Is there anyone able to help

I have this example
#[OA\RequestBody(
content: new OA\MediaType(
mediaType:"multipart/form-data",
)
)]
but not work, I have the impression that the MediaType is not displayed

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```php
#[OA\RequestBody(
    content: [
        new OA\MediaType(
            mediaType: 'multipart/form-data',
            schema: new OA\Schema(properties: [
                new OA\Property(
                    property: 'avatar',
                    type: 'file',
                ),
            ])
        ),
    ]
)]
```

or from model:

```php
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\Model;
use OpenApi\Attributes\MediaType;
use OpenApi\Attributes\RequestBody;
use OpenApi\Attributes\Schema;


#[RequestBody(
    required: true,
    content: [
        new MediaType(
            mediaType: 'multipart/form-data',
            schema: new Schema(ref: new Model(type: AvatarRequest::class))
        ),
    ]
)]

###

use OpenApi\Attributes\Property;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Image;

class AvatarRequest
{
    #[Property(type: 'file')]
    #[Image(maxSize: '2M', mimeTypes: [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/png',
        'image/webp',
    ])]
    public UploadedFile $avatar;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @vodevel, could you provide an example how to bind validated AvatarRequest object into controller as argument? Could we use #[MapRequestPayload] or something like that without using custom argumentResolver?

Comment: Hi, jeka! Good question, but I don't know the answer) I prefer the [ValueResolver](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/value_resolver.html#adding-a-custom-value-resolver) approach. It allows you to avoid polluting the controller with attribute markers, but requires a custom ArgumentValueResolver. Here's [an example](https://github.com/prugala/symfony-request-dto/blob/main/src/ArgumentResolver/RequestDtoArgumentResolver.php), if you're interested.